# Authorizing access to health data

Tags: swift, frameworks, healthkit, swift-framework

I would like to request the HealthKit data here, but I keep getting a lot of error messages from the compiler. Does anyone know what the problem is here? Here is the code:

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    
    
    
    let allTypes = Set([HKObjectType.workoutType(),
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!,
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceCycling)!,
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!,
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!])


    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: allTypes, read: allTypes) { (success, error) in
        if !success {
            // Handle the error here.
        }
    }
```

I used the Apple Developer Documentation and did all exactly like it was written. Obviously, it didn't worked. Does anyone know the solution? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: Don't you need a privacy entitlement in Info.plist?

Comment: What is the compiler issues that you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Before requesting HealthKit data you need to set usage description entries in your apps plist.

> `NSHealthShareUsageDescription` customizes the message for reading
> data.
>
> `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription` customizes the message for writing
> data.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614152-requestauthorization#discussion

on top of that, you also need to add `HealthKit` in your app capabilities/entitlements otherwise you will get

`Error: Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement.`